# Trouble Sending transaction using PHP curl and TRON api

Tags: php, curl, transactions, tron

I am playing around with the TRON api and trying to send transactions using the PHP curl method. I can successfully send the transaction in the TRON Developer sandbox but get and error when executing it on my server.

Error im receiving -

```
status_code: 200
{"result": {"code": "CONTRACT_VALIDATE_ERROR","message": "313a39343a20494e56414c49442068657820537472696e67"}}
```

My php Curl request -

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers  = [
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];
$postData = [
'privateKey' => 'MY Private Key',
'toAddress' => 'To Address',
'amount' => '100000'
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/easytransferbyprivate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result     = curl_exec ($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $statusCode;
print_r($result);
```

Here is the link to the TRON sandbox im using -

```
https://developers.tron.network/reference#east-transfer-by-private-key
```

The success code in the sandbox is 200 so not sure why im receiving that and I am not sure how to lookup the returned error message, any idea what im doing wrong?

This is the sample post request given from TRON -

```
curl -X POST  https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/easytransferbyprivate -d '{"privateKey": "D95611A9AF2A2A45359106222ED1AFED48853D9A44DEFF8DC7913F5CBA727366", "toAddress":"4112E621D5577311998708F4D7B9F71F86DAE138B5","amount":10000}'
```

Comment: google CONTRACT_VALIDATE_ERROR your find a few references which say its not a valid account. are you using sandbox stuff on live?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes I googled it but not much info as to why the error. I know the private key is valid and the to_address is valid. They are live accounts with a few TRX in them. When I send from the sandbox I get the transfer.

Comment: It seems like its not recognizing the credentials for the contract in the request. Is there a different way to post the data other than sending as raw json?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I was preparing the data wrong..

Instead creating an array -

```
$postData = [
    'privateKey' => 'MY Private Key',
    'toAddress' => 'To Address',
    'amount' => '100000'
];
```

I needed to do the literal string and not encode it.

```
$postData = '{"privateKey": "xxx", "toAddress..etc
```

Just like in the example given in the sandbox.